# Android Binder modeling question - MusicStore, IMusicStore.aidl, Music, IMusic.aidl

Tags: android, api, ipc, modeling, aidl

Android Binder document has an simple example about how to pass an object Rect through Binder interface, I'm wondering how to do the modeling if the object itself has some methods which are also defined by AIDL interface?

For example, project A owns MusicStoreManager, project B owns MusicStore and Music, the interaction is through Binder IPC. I'm using IMusicStore.aidl defines a method "IMusic getMusic(int musicId)", and the IMusic.aidl defineds a method "byte[] getMusicData(int from, int to)", but I'm stuck here:

1. How to model the Music class, the IMusic interface, and the IMusic.stub on the project B in general?
2. Should or CAN the getMusic() method return a IMusic.Stub instance or Music instance in the following code?
3. How to understand the IMusic.Stub?
4. Does the class Music has to implement IMusic interface as well as Parcelable?

Many thanks - I'm really confused.

```
public class MusicStoreService extends Service {
    ...
    protected static final IMusicStore.Stub store = new IMusicStore.Stub() {
        ...
        public IMusic getMusic(int id) throws RemoteException {
            return new Music(id); // or return new IMusic.Stub() ???
        }
    }
    ...
    protected static final IMusic.Stub music = new IMusic.Stub() {
        ...
        public byte[] getMusicData(int from, int to) throws RemoteException {
            // open the associated file, read the data within range, return it back.
        }
    }
    ...
}

public class Music extends Object implements Parcelable, IMusic {
    ...
    public byte[] getMusicData(int from, int to) throws RemoteException {
        // open the associated file, read the data within range, return it back.
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can tell you a recipe that works: for interfaces defined via AIDL, always create instances of the `.Stub` class. Don't apply the interface randomly on other classes.

> For example, project A owns MusicStoreManager, project B owns MusicStore and Music

Project B should be creating subclasses of `IMusicStore.Stub` and `IMusic.Stub`. `MusicStoreService` would return an instance of the `IMusicStore.Stub` class from `onBind()`, so Project A can get the `IMusicStore` proxy via `bindService()`. The implementation of `getMusic()` on the `IMusicStore.Stub` class would return an instance of an `IMusic.Stub` class.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The IMusic.Stub() constructor does not have parameter, how to associate the stub object with a real Music object as the MusicStore contains a HashMap for all the Music objects.  Should the getMusic() method return Music object type or IMusic interface type? Thanks.

Comment: @user506376: There are no "real Music objects", AFAICT. Put your "real Music object" smarts on your IMusic.Stub subclass. "Should the getMusic() method return Music object type or IMusic interface type? " -- it has to return an `IMusic.Stub` AFAIK.

Comment: If the name of the IMusic.aidl is changed to IMusicAccessor.aidl, one can create a api to associate music id with a internel Music object (open, create, get, etc). But this is not really what I want. My question is if I can use Binder IPC at the same time still comply with the interface definition? In other words, if it is possible to modeling service oriented IPC mechanism in object oriented API flavor? Thanks.

Comment: @user506376: You are no longer making sense to me, so I cannot help you further.

Comment: Finally got it working - the stub objects are the music objects. Thanks for your help.